# Update a view page content without refreshing the page

Tags: 7, nodes, views

Is there a module that updates a view automatically when it is changed, without refreshing the view page?

For example, when a new node is added to the view or deleted from the view, or a node is edited, the view is automatically updated without refreshing the page.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Views Hacks module](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) (poorly named in my opinion) has an auto-refresh submodule that should accomplish this for you. You may want to also look at using the [Views content cache module](http://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) so that you can still enable caching on your view.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find the answer to this for some time and I don't think I can improve on the previous answer.... but I think it is not really correct.

The way I would approach it is to put more of the Views formatting functionality in some JQuery Javascript so that the Javascript fetched the data for the View from the Drupal server via JSON and not HTML.

Then periodically - rather than using Views Hacks autofresh - it would say "give me all the records for this view which are newer than this datetime"

Unfortunately this would require hand coding for now as I have not seen this in any contributed module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_refresh or just use the code below in your JS to refresh the view.

```
$('.view-dom-id-403402eee35f68cd32fe87b45702dc63').triggerHandler('RefreshView');
```